# SubmitChanges() doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I don't know what's wrong with this code , this code compile successfully but doesn't update database . do i miss some thing ?

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
var query = from p in db.AllPatiences
            select p;
int newID = 1001;
foreach (AllPatience patient in query)
{
    patient.Id = newID.ToString();
    newID++;
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Must be something odd about your setup - works like a charm for me. The code seems just fine - I don't think that your code is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem , For Update like that , It's necessary to have primary key . The reason my table didn't have primary key was : I imported those data from an Excel file , So i didn't have Primary key .

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're working with a file-based database (.mdf) in your project, and you're trying to look at the table data in that database. When you build your project, the database is cloned into the bin/debug/ or bin/release/ directory, where your running program accesses it. If you take a look at this version of the file, rather than the one you have loaded into your VS project, you should see the changes.

If this is the case, you should set the database file property to "Copy only if newer" or "Do not copy", to avoid it cloning the DB each build.

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong :( . I'm Not using File-Based Database .

Answer (score 2):

is patient.Id generated in the database itself? Possibly as an SQL IDENTITY field?
Also, check the SyncOn property of the field in your dbml file.

Answer (score 1):

Guess, is "Id" your tables primary key? If so, I don't think that L2S supports an update of the primary key (what's very correct in my opinion). You should never attend to change the value of the primary key.

If Id is not your primary key, I have no clue :-P.